# How to delete last comma from comma separated words string in php?

Tags: php, string

Let's say my string like:

```
$string = 'lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet, ';
```

or `$string = 'lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet,';`

How to transform that to something like this?

```
$string = 'lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet';
```

// the string is generated by this code:

```
$count = count($taglist);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$videoData['tags'] .= $taglist[$i].', ';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$string = rtrim($string, ', ');
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing this string is being built programmatically elsewhere via a loop like this:

```
$str = '';
some loop {
    $str .= $item . ', ';
}
```

And you're left over with an extra ", " at the end of the loop. If this is the case, I'd recommend doing this instead:

```
$list = array();
some loop {
    $list[] = $item;
}
$str = implode(', ', $list);
```

Comment: Then all you need to do is throw away that whole loop and just use: implode(", ", $taglist);

Answer (score 3):

```
trim($string, " ,");
```

Removes trailing commas (plus the default spaces, newlines etc) from both start and end of the string.

Comment: This doesn't remove the spaces (or the comma, for that matter). You need to specify whitespace in the second parameter. http://codepad.org/oKig4gTI

Comment: My bad, need to add space to the charlist. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = substr(trim($string),0,-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

A less PHP specific soultion that is a convention, and good habit to get into is this...

```
var modString = "";
for(var i = 0; i < LIMIT_NUM; i++) {
    if(modString.length() > 0) modString += ",";
    modString += "content";
}
```

This is simalary to javascript code but the idea is simple...check if the string has anything in it and if it does add the comma BEFORE the content.This will work in any language and is the way i see it done most often. You need conventions for this sort of thing vs. calling a library for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$string = rtrim($string, ', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `substr(trim($string),0,-1)` to remove last char and whitespaces.